# Use regexrelace to delete text which has a pattern

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have cells that have image dimensions in the format of `##x##` or `###x###` (width x height) and I want to delete these values and keep the rest of the text inside the cell. These dimensions might be at the beginning, end or anywhere in the cell. These dimensions have many combinations (width x height). I am thinking of `regexreplace` but don't know how. Any other idea that works will do.

Example of cells:

```
adidas Deerupt S  AT 300x250
adidas Deerupt S   AT 160x600
Nike Air Max Week DE 320x50
Nike Air Max Week DE 160x600
Nike Air Max Week AT 160x600
COMFYCUSH AT 250x250
Winter Sale III. AT 250x250
Winter Sale III. DE 320x50
Winter Sale III. AT 160x600
Winter Sale II. DE 160x600
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+x\d+")), "")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Awesome. Works great. Couldn't figure out the "\d+x\d+" part. Thanks again.

Comment: "\d+x\d+" = "number followed by x folowed by number"